# Directed graph implementation

Tags: c++, graph

I need to implement a digraph(Directed graph) in c++ as part of a homework and I'm having some issues with how to represent the vertices and edges data types.
Can anybody please point me to a example or a simple c++ class that implements this so I can study it and extend from there?

I've googled for a bit but I only found results about using Boost or other libraries, I just need something simple that doesn't rely on any library.

Thank you.

Comment: digraph is the standard graph theory nomenclature.

Comment: @Neil: see http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digraph

Comment: @Greg See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs - but I'll delete my comment.

Comment: hai guyz, turns out words can have two meanings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph

Comment: @Neil: right, there are two etymologies listed on that dictionary page, the character-oriented one is the Etymology 2.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two major ways of representing digraphs with data structures:

**Node centric**. This method represents each *node* as an object within your program, and each node contains information about other nodes it links to. The other nodes can be as simple as a list of nodes where there exists a directed edge between the current node and the target node.

**Edge centric**. This method represents each *edge* as an object within your program, and each edge contains information about which nodes it connects. In a digraph, each edge will have exactly one "source" and "destination" node (which may be the same node if you're considering self-loops). This method is essentially a list of ordered pairs.

Depending on the problem you're solving, one of these two basic forms will end up being most appropriate. More specific algorithms might need to add more information to the above basic structures, such as for example a list of all nodes reachable from the current node.

Answer (score 3):

Loosely, there are 2 straightforward ways of representing graphs:

1. Connection Matrix
2. List of Lists.

Each has advantages/disadvantages, depending on the application.

#2 will involve a lot of pointer fiddling.

#1 is often easier to use when doing graph transformationss.

In either one, you're going to have something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class node
{
   public:
   T data;
};
```

And the matrix and list of list classes will be pointing to dynamically allocated `node`'s.

The implication is that you will have a `graph` class and a `node` class.

Comment: Connection matrix is only appropriate for dense graphs, and dense graphs are relatively uncommon. You really need to specify this. Typically the uses of dense and sparse representations are mutually exclusive, and there are all kinds of sparse representations which aren't anything like a list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

Try a `vector< NodeType >` with a `multimap< NodeType *, EdgeType>`.

`multimap` doesn't support subscripting `[ x ]` so you'll need to use `edges.lower_bound()` instead.

Alternatively, a `map< pair< NodeType *, NodeType * >, EdgeType >` can help look for an edge given two nodes. I used exactly that in one pretty heavy-duty program.

Here's an example for the first suggestion:

```
struct NodeType {
    int distance;
    NodeType( int d ) { distance = d; }
};
struct EdgeType  {
    int weight;
    NodeType *link;
    EdgeType( int w, NodeType *l ) { weight = w; link = l }
};

vector< NodeType > nodes;
nodes.reserve( 3 );
nodes.push_back( NodeType( 0 ) );
nodes.push_back( NodeType( 0 ) );
nodes.push_back( NodeType( 0 ) );

multimap< NodeType *, EdgeType > edges;
edges.insert( make_pair( &nodes[0], EdgeType( 4, &nodes[2] ) ) );
edges.insert( make_pair( &nodes[0], EdgeType( 1, &nodes[1] ) ) );
edges.insert( make_pair( &nodes[2], EdgeType( 2, &nodes[0] ) ) );

for ( multimap< NodeType *, EdgeType >::iterator iter = edges.lower_bound( &nodes[1] ),
  end = edges.upper_bound( &nodes[1] ); iter != end; ++ iter ) {
    cerr << "1 connects to " << iter->second.link - nodes.begin() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [university paper](http://hamilton.bell.ac.uk/swdev2/notes/notes_18.pdf) might help you.

It's not the most complete, but it gives you an idea perhaps. I found it rather useful, it's also for a lecture so there is no risk of copying anything one shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>
class node
{
public:
    T data;
    vector<node<T>*> edges;
}
```

You will most likely also want to store a `list<node<dataType>*>` of all the nodes.